# Vue Router 4 - nested 404 (not found) routes redirect not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router

these are my routes:

```js
const routes: Array<RouteRecordRaw> = [
  {
    path: "/projects",
    component: {},
    children: [
      { path: "extensions", component: {} },
      { path: "themes", component: {} },
      { path: ":pathMatch(.*)*", redirect: "extensions" },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: "/about",
    component: {},
    children: [
      { path: "experience", component: {} },
      { path: "documents", component: {} },
      { path: ":pathMatch(.*)*", redirect: "experience" },
    ],
  },
  { path: "/:pathMatch(.*)*", redirect: "/projects/extensions" },
];
```

Expected result:

Navigating to /projects or /projects/asdasd -> redirects to /projects/extensions
Navigating to /about or /about/asdasd -> redirects to /about/experience
Navigating to /asdasdasd -> redirects to /projects/extensions

---

Current result:
Every incorrect path redirects me to /projects/extensions

I tried many combinations but nothing works as expected, please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Redirecting to child route

To redirect `/projects` to `/projects/extensions`, add a child route with a blank `path` that redirects to the target route:

```js
const routes: Array<RouteRecordRaw> = [
  {
    path: "/projects",
    component: () => import("../views/ProjectsView.vue"),
    children: [
      {
        path: "",
        redirect: "/projects/extensions", // or use a named route (see below)
      },
      ⋮
    ],
  },
}
```

### Getting the `redirect` target right

When the `redirect` string is not an *absolute path* to a route (i.e., `/about/experience`), the path would be *relative to the **current** route*.

For instance, imagine being at `/projects/themes` and clicking `/about/foo`. This is how the final route would resolve:

1. `/about/foo` matches the wildcard route under `/about`, which redirects to `/projects/themes/experience`.
2. `/projects/themes/experience` matches the outer wildcard route, which redirects to `/projects/extensions`.

There are a couple ways to solve this...

##### Option 1: Use absolute path in `redirect` string

```js
const routes: Array<RouteRecordRaw> = [
  {
    path: "/projects",
    component: () => import("../views/ProjectsView.vue"),
    children: [
      {
        path: "extensions",
        component: () => import("../views/ProjectsExtensions.vue"),
      },
      {
        path: "themes",
        component: () => import("../views/ProjectsThemes.vue"),
      },                                       
      { path: ":pathMatch(.*)*", redirect: "/projects/extensions" },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: "/about",
    component: () => import("../views/AboutView.vue"),
    children: [
      {
        path: "experience",
        component: () => import("../views/AboutExperience.vue"),
      },
      {
        path: "documents",
        component: () => import("../views/AboutDocuments.vue"),
      },                                       
      { path: ":pathMatch(.*)*", redirect: "/about/experience" },
    ],
  },                                       
  { path: "/:pathMatch(.*)*", redirect: "/projects/extensions" },
]
```

[demo 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-router-redirects?file=src%2Frouter.ts)

##### Option 2: Use [named route](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-routes.html#named-routes) in `redirect` object

```js
const routes: Array<RouteRecordRaw> = [
  {
    path: "/projects",
    component: () => import("../views/ProjectsView.vue"),
    children: [
      {
        path: "extensions",
          
        name: "proj-ext",
        component: () => import("../views/ProjectsExtensions.vue"),
      },
      {
        path: "themes",
        component: () => import("../views/ProjectsThemes.vue"),
      },                                       
      { path: ":pathMatch(.*)*", redirect: { name: "proj-ext" } },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: "/about",
    component: () => import("../views/AboutView.vue"),
    children: [
      {
        path: "experience",
          
        name: "about-exp",
        component: () => import("../views/AboutExperience.vue"),
      },
      {
        path: "documents",
        component: () => import("../views/AboutDocuments.vue"),
      },                                       
      { path: ":pathMatch(.*)*", redirect: { name: "about-exp" } },
    ],
  },                                        
  { path: "/:pathMatch(.*)*", redirect: { name: "proj-ext" } },
]
```

[demo 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-router-redirects-furktg?file=src%2Frouter.ts)

Named routes are easier to maintain than paths, as (1) they avoid having to enter long paths, and (2) they could be moved without having to refactor paths.